# Did i confuse the integer data type with something else?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-livewire

I dont know how to deal with the error of unsupported operand types: int + App\Models\Rating but the calculation works just correctly. It pinpoints the error to the public function rate starting from this currentRating = round. Im confused because it's new to me in terms of the language so it's big blur.

```
     <div class="w-full space-y-5">
         <p class="font-medium text-blue-500 uppercase">
             Rating: <strong>{{ $currentRating }}</strong> ⭐ 
         </p>
     </div>
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Rating;

class MovieRatings extends Component
{
    public $rating;
    public $ratings;
    public $currentRating = '-';
    public $comment;
    public $currentId;
    public $movie;
    public $hideForm;

    protected $rules = [
        'rating' => ['required', 'in:1,2,3,4,5'],
        'comment' => 'required',

    ];

    public function mount() 
    {
        if(auth()->user()){
            $rating = Rating::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->where('movie_id', $this->movie->id)->first();
            if (!empty($rating)) {
                $this->rating  = $rating->rating;
                $this->comment = $rating->comment;
                $this->currentId = $rating->id;
            }
            $this->ratings = Rating::where('movie_id', $this->movie->id)->get();
            if ($this->ratings->count()) {
            $this->currentRating = round($this->ratings->sum('rating') / $this->ratings->count(), 2) . ' / 5 (' . $this->ratings->count() . ' votes)';
            }
        }
        return view('livewire.movie-ratings');
    }

    public function rate() 
    {
        $rating = Rating::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->where('movie_id', $this->movie->id)->first();
        $this->validate();
        if (!empty($rating)) {
            $rating->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
            $rating->movie_id = $this->movie->id;
            $rating->rating = $this->rating;
            $rating->comment = $this->comment;
            $rating->status = 1;
            try {
                $rating->update();
                $this->currentRating = round(($this->ratings->sum('rating') + $rating) / ($this->ratings->count() + 1), 2);
            } catch (\Throwable $th) {
                throw $th;
            }
            session()->flash('message', 'Success!');
        } else {
            $rating = new Rating;
            $rating->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
            $rating->movie_id = $this->movie->id;
            $rating->rating = $this->rating;
            $rating->comment = $this->comment;
            $rating->status = 1;
            
            try {
                $rating->save();
                $this->currentRating = round(($this->ratings->sum('rating') + $rating) / ($this->ratings->count() + 1), 2) . ' / 5 (' . ($this->ratings->count() + 1) . ' votes)';

            } catch (\Throwable $th) {
                throw $th;
            }
            $this->hideForm = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you get an error message, please post the complete error message and point out where in the posted code it happens. If you don't get an error message, then please explain the actual issue in detail.

Comment: `$rating` clearly is an object, so what sense is `+ $rating` supposed to make?

Comment: was trying to calculate the average of the rating by sum up all the rating and divide with the number of people that rated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably meant to write `+ $rating->rating` instead of `+ $rating`.

`$rating` is an object, not an integer.